# Взять определенные значения из колонки и вставить их в другие колонки по значению pandas

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, csv

Помогите пожалуйста понять логику.
Вот у меня считало csv файл и создало одну общую колонку для всех строк файла. Я же создала несколько других колонок и теперь хочу из этой одной общей колонки распределить значения по разным колонкам
Например мне нужно из колонки взять все номера телефонов и вставить в колонку с названием 'Номер телефона:', дальше например сумма за месяц : и вставить это в сумму за месяц.Я новичок в pandas.И обычно работают уже с упорядоченными по колонкам файлами.но у меня колонка получилось одна. Искусственно я создала еще несколько и хочу распределить значения по ним!!!Спасибо за любую помощь.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
    
dframe1 = pd.read_csv('text.csv')
columns = ['Контракт', 'Номер телефона', 'Всего по контракту', 'Стоимость пакета за месяц']
data_old = pd.read_csv('text.csv', header=None, names=columns)
data_old[['Контракт', 'Номер телефона']] = data_old['Номер телефона'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

Все данные хранятся в колонке Контракт.Помогите пожалуйста ссылкой или советом как лучше реализовать.я застряла.Спасибо!!!

Вот данные из Jupyter Notebook при чтении csv файла.
Только в колонке контракт все строки

```
Контракт    Номер телефона  Всего по контракту  Стоимость пакета за месяц
0   ЩОМІСЯЧНА ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА ТА ПОСЛ НАДАНІ ЗА МВ...   NaN NaN NaN
1   ПОСЛУГИ, НАДАНІ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:99.3961    NaN NaN NaN
2   Вихідні дзвінки з України за кордон,.1960   NaN NaN NaN
3   ЗАМОВЛЕНІ ДОДАТКОВІ ПОСЛУГИ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:,...   NaN NaN NaN
4   Вартість послуги "Корпоративна мережа"0.0000    NaN NaN NaN
255 ЗАГАЛОМ ЗА КОНТРАКТОМ (БЕЗ ПДВ ТА ПФ):80.0807   NaN NaN NaN
256 Контракт № 3567488500 Номер телефону: 38039...  NaN NaN NaN
257 Тарифний Пакет: RED Business S  NaN NaN NaN
258 ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА:0.0000,0.0000   NaN NaN NaN
259 ЗАГАЛОМ ЗА КОНТРАКТОМ (БЕЗ ПДВ ТА ПФ):0.0000    NaN NaN NaN
```

Начальные данные из файла:

```
ЩОМІСЯЧНА ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА ТА ПОСЛ НАДАНІ ЗА МВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА:99
"ПОСЛУГИ, НАДАНІ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:99.3961"
"Вихідні дзвінки з України за кордон,.1960"
"ЗАМОВЛЕНІ ДОДАТКОВІ ПОСЛУГИ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:,133.5484"
"Вартість послуги ""Корпоративна мережа""0.0000"
Контракт № 39533533333  Номер телефону: 3800000000
Тарифний Пакет: RED Business S
"ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА:78.4314,78.4314"
"ПОСЛУГИ, НАДАНІ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:41.8826"
ЗАГАЛОМ ЗА КОНТРАКТОМ (БЕЗ ПДВ ТА ПФ):120.3140
Контракт № 56003646573  Номер телефону: 380647777777
Тарифний Пакет: RED Business S
"ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА:70.4314,70.4314"
ЗАГАЛОМ ЗА КОНТРАКТОМ (БЕЗ ПДВ ТА ПФ):78.4314
Контракт № 322322214621  Номер телефону: 380993439922
Тарифний Пакет: RED Business S
"ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА:78.4314,78.4314"
"ПОСЛУГИ, НАДАНІ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА:16.9413"
ЗАГАЛОМ ЗА КОНТРАКТОМ (БЕЗ ПДВ ТА ПФ):95.3727
```

Comment: добавьте пример исходных данных в свой вопрос. Есть подозрение, что все ваши проблемы возникают из-за неправильного парсинга csv

Comment: вы можете чать самого csv-файла выложить, а не результат его чтения? речь как-раз о парсинге файла идет.

Comment: добавила, просмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Masha, это не CSV файл... Можете объяснить структуру записей? Где начинается запись, где заканчивается? Похоже, сначала вам придется парсить текстовый файл регулярками и уже потом создавать фрейм из данных, полученных после парсинга

Comment: да.уверена что из за неправильного Парсинга без регулярок ничего не выйдет!Спасибо!